# Aspect orientation in C#

Tags: c#, aspect

I have a `FTPDataTransfer`-class that has a state (`FTPDataTransferState`). This class provides a lot of transfer-methods like `ReceiveData` (overloaded), `SendData`, ...
How can I change the state to `Ready`, `Transfer`, ... without chaning the value in every transfer-method?

Comment: doesn't the value of `FTPDataTransferState` depend on logic performed in mentioned methods...?

Comment: Yes, but it is redundant and uncomfortable... I had to write `state = FTPDataTransferState.Transfer` and at the end `state = FTPDataTransferState.Ready` in every method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) for this. In more detail, the [`OnMethodBoundaryAspect`](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-4-OnMethodBoundaryAspect.aspx) is the aspect you want to use. In your case it could look like:

```
using PostSharp.Aspects;

[Serializable]
public sealed class ReadyOnExit : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var state = (FTPDataTransferState)args.Instance;
        state.Transfer(FTPDataTransferState.Ready);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The leading AOP toolkit for .NET is [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). The way it would work in your case is that you'd define a custom attribute specifying the state that should be set when the method is to execute, apply the attribute to the appropriate methods, and define (in one place) the code setting/resetting the state. The toolkit would make this code run when the methods are entered/left.